# Write down the window to viewport transformation matrix if the viewport PQRS is normalize in the range of [-1,1]

Tags: matrix

What exactly will be the final matrix?
"Consider a window ABCD whose lower left corner is A (XWL,YWL) and the upper
right corner C is (XWm, YWM). A viewport PQRS has been defined with the lower
1eft corner is P (XVL , YVL ) , and the upper right corner is R(XVm,YVm) . The window ABCD has to be mapped into the viewport PQRS."

What will be the window to viewport transformation matrix if the viewport PQRS
is normalize in the range of [-1,11].

Comment: All of the image flip, reverse, mirror can be done by manipulating the identity matrix. Either by negating values or by changing the row/columns. ) Image scaling can be done by manipulating the diagonal as well. Values larger then 1 scale up, values smaller then 1 scale down. So if an image needs to be scaled from 1024,1024 to 1,1 range then the scale is just 1/1024. Combining the to matrices gives the final transformation.